# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, gauge

I am trying to manage to work the following example [MeterGauge](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/metergauge.xhtml) Since the xhtml code is not complete that you can use it to make an entire xhtml page, I have taken the missing tags from [PrimeFaces official doc](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf) at page 12.
Then created the JavaBean file ChartView.java (taking the code from MeterGauge sample page) and tried running it on a GlassFish server, but it failed, as you can see from logs

**metergauge2.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>


<p:chart type="metergauge" model="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModel1}" style="width:400px;height:250px" />

<p:chart type="metergauge" model="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModel2}" style="width:400px;height:250px" />


</h:body>
</html>
```

**ChartView.java**

```
package sources;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.MeterGaugeChartModel;

@ManagedBean
public class ChartView implements Serializable {

    private MeterGaugeChartModel meterGaugeModel1;
    private MeterGaugeChartModel meterGaugeModel2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        createMeterGaugeModels();
    }

    public MeterGaugeChartModel getMeterGaugeModel1() {
        return meterGaugeModel1;
    }

    public MeterGaugeChartModel getMeterGaugeModel2() {
        return meterGaugeModel2;
    }

    private MeterGaugeChartModel initMeterGaugeModel() {
        List<Number> intervals = new ArrayList<Number>(){{
            add(20);
            add(50);
            add(120);
            add(220);
        }};

        return new MeterGaugeChartModel(140, intervals);
    }

    private void createMeterGaugeModels() {
        meterGaugeModel1 = initMeterGaugeModel();
        meterGaugeModel1.setTitle("MeterGauge Chart");
        meterGaugeModel1.setGaugeLabel("km/h");

        meterGaugeModel2 = initMeterGaugeModel();
        meterGaugeModel2.setTitle("Custom Options");
        meterGaugeModel2.setSeriesColors("66cc66,93b75f,E7E658,cc6666");
        meterGaugeModel2.setGaugeLabel("km/h");
        meterGaugeModel2.setGaugeLabelPosition("bottom");
        meterGaugeModel2.setShowTickLabels(false);
        meterGaugeModel2.setLabelHeightAdjust(110);
        meterGaugeModel2.setIntervalOuterRadius(100);
    }

}
```

**Glassfish logs**

```
2015-07-17T16:51:23.536+0200|Grave: Error Rendering View[/metergauge2.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData(MeterGaugeRenderer.java:33)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:98)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-07-17T16:51:23.601+0200|Avvertenza: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData(MeterGaugeRenderer.java:33)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:98)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: in the getter of the model chart you need to test if is null or not: as following:

 public MeterGaugeChartModel getMeterGaugeChartModel l() {
  
   if (meterGaugeChartModel == null) {
    meterGaugeChartModel = new MeterGaugeChartModel ();
       }
  return meterGaugeChartModel ;
 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/chart/renderer/MeterGaugeRenderer.java) based on stack trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.MeterGaugeRenderer.encodeData(MeterGaugeRenderer.java:33)
```

`MeterGaugeRenderer#encodeData()` [line 33](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/chart/renderer/MeterGaugeRenderer.java#L33) is below:

```
33    writer.write(",data:[[" + model.getValue() + "]]");
```

The `writer` definitely can't be null at that point. So, logically, `model` is `null`.

Upon closer inspection of the `<p:chart model>` attribute, it appears that they made a mistake in their showcase in its current form. Look closer at the managed bean names.

```
<p:chart ... model="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModel1}" />
```

```
@ManagedBean
public class ChartView implements Serializable {}
```

Indeed, they don't match.

So, solution is: either use `#{chartView.meterGaugeModel1}` in view, or rename backing bean class to `ChartBean`.

Comment: Oh yeah. I noticed that incongruence between bean name and its reference in xhtml page, but I entered ChartView instead of chartView :-). Now I am going to report the error to PrimeFaces developers

Comment: @BalusC Facing this exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BarRenderer.encodeData(BarRenderer.java:35)`