# NullPointerException at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BarRenderer.encodeData

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I hope my question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478841/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-primefaces-component-chart-renderer-meterg) but unfortunately answer is not working for me.

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{lasDashboardBean.barModel}" style="height:350px">
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{lasDashboardBean.itemSelect}"  update="machineInfoTable"  />
                        </p:chart>
```

**LasDashboardBean.java**

```
@Named(value = "lasDashboardBean")
@Dependent
public class LasDashboardBean {

private BarChartModel barModel;
private DashboardController dashboardDbController;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        dashboardDbController = new DashboardController();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LasDashboardBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    createBarModel();

}
private void createBarModel() {
    barModel = initBarModel();
    barModel.setTitle("Machine Menufacturers Count");
    barModel.setLegendPosition("ne");

    Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setTickAngle(90);

    Axis yAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Count");
    yAxis.setMin(0);
}
private BarChartModel initBarModel() {
    BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();
    ChartSeries manufacturersMachines = new ChartSeries();
    manufacturersMachines.setLabel("Machines");
    try {

        manufacturersMachineCount = dashboardDbController.getManufacturersMachinesCount();

        manufacturersMachineCount.stream().forEach((mc) -> {
            manufacturersMachines.set(mc.getManufacturerName(), mc.getCount());
        });

        model.addSeries(manufacturersMachines);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LasDashboardBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return model;

}
```

**Error Log:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BarRenderer.encodeData(BarRenderer.java:35)
>       at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
>       at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:95)
>       at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:68)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:949)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1912)
>       at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeGridBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:244)
>       at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeGridLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:90)
>       at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:40)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:949)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1912)
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:491)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
>       at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>       at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>       at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
>       at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: You are missing setter() and getter() for barModel in your bean.

Comment: @Melloware They are present, just didn't mention them in code.

Comment: ahh please always include the full example else to helpers like me it looks like your bean is not bean compliant and of course would not work.  Please update for others.

Comment: Also it might not like @Dependent scope have you tried RequestScoped or ViewScoped?

Comment: Not just a 'full' example, a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced same issue on [Glassfish Server](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/overview/index.html).
After changing server, issue was resolved.

Comment: Yeah! It did resolved the problem but as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478841/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-primefaces-component-chart-renderer-meterg, I am not yet clarified what is the reason.